# Uncertain graduate study plans due to timing problems with visa and professor's funding

Tags: graduate-admissions, email, international-students, visa

I applied for the University of Alberta. Fortunately I have got funding opportunity through my prospective professor's grant. I have applied for a visa expecting to go with the January intake, and waited for 6 months to get the entrance visa. As my visa came late I decided to start in the spring semester (May). I contacted my professor 3 weeks ago (in March) and he said he had a good job for me if I can come by May.

Yesterday, I finally got my visa and thus I contacted him again. My prof told me not to come for the May semester as "I have to give your project to other one since your visa delayed". And it seems he is on a sabbatical leave.

He says he does not have funding for me until September and my funding status will be clarified in 3 months. I already have my visa and I have done all the things that I needed to go. Now I am up in the air.

If I accept that I come in Aug/Sep, how can I make sure that he is going to fund me in 3 months? What he decided devastated my plans for starting my term in May. **How can I ask for a guarantee?** I think he should assure that he will give me the fund in 3 months since I have been waiting for 1 year now.

+from India and I need an entrance visa.

Comment: Do you have to use your entrance visa before September?

Comment: Hello, I sympathise with your situation but it is unclear what you're asking for exactly.

Comment: Hi if he "gave your project to somebody else as your visa was delyaed" means you notified him your visa was delayed. What was his initial answer? I feel you need to add more information. As for your question, I believe it is "can I make hime change his mind? Can I be assured he will fund me in September?" If so please rephrase, and we will try to help

Comment: You could also ask “how can your professor be sure you will turn up when he gives you the date in September”... meeting a start date cuts both ways.

Comment: Unless you have a contract you cannot be sure to have an employment. If you had a contract which stated a starting day in May and you had to breach the contract you probably need a new contract.

Comment: @Scaahu Yes I want to go 2 months earlier.

Comment: @farmargar The edit button is not active. my question is" how can my  I make sure that the professor will give me fund after 2 months?

Comment: What do you mean?@solar Mike

Comment: @nikki2 in your first paragraph you said you expected to start in Jan - so your professor expected you then. You let them down by not arriving - visa etc. So, how can your professor be sure you will arrive in September? Will the professor keep the funding if you decide to arrive in Oct - lost passport, wedding etc etc ... who knows - trust comes from both sides.

Comment: Adding a Canada tag based on your other questions.

Comment: @solar Mike is it polite to tell him that trust comes from both sides? And want him to keep my funding?

Comment: It would definitely not be polite to do so. This would suggest that the prof is displaying problematic behavior, while the fact that you did not come when you promised to come is a big part of the problem. He trusted you, and you broke that trust. So the question is not how can you trust him, but how can he trust you. The way forward for you is to keep your promises and hope that that will be reciprocated.

Comment: @MaartenBuis we do not know whether the visa delay was due to some bureaucrat, or to nikki2. Before knowing that, you should refrain from using hurtful comments.

Comment: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/108771/uncertain-graduate-study-plans-due-to-timing-problems-with-visa-and-professors

Answer (score 2):

> Why he acts like this?

We cannot know, but there are plausible reasons. Some of my funding is available in the form "use it [in this time period] or lose it." If I have a project like that and a student indicates that it is likely (s)he cannot come, I will give that project to someone else rather than lose the money entirely. Here the prof has to make an educated guess: (s)he wants to avoid the situation you are in, but we have all been let down by students who promised they would come, but at the last moment did not. So apparently your professor made the guess that you would not be able to make it.

> how can my I make sure that the professor will give me fund after 2 months?

If you have a contract, but apparently you didn't have one, so that suggests that you are from a country where it is common to sign such a contract at the very last moment or where funding is not considered a form of employment and thus there is no employment contract. As you can see that is hugely dependent on the local laws and customs. In those cases, the answer is: you cannot be sure. Since we don't know which country you are in, there is little more we can say.

Comment: He gave me a letter which indicate my funding and duration of it. This letter came from the professor, not from university, since the source  of funding is prof's grant.

Comment: In my university, it is the university alone that employs people. This is true regardless of how I collected the money. So only a contract with the university would count, and a letter from me would be worthless. Again whether this applies to you depends on your jurisdiction.

Comment: where is your university?  @Maarten Buis

Comment: The more important question is where is yours.

Comment: @MaartenBuis From the OP's other questions, it looks like Canada.

Comment: @Maarten Buis  university of Alberta.